# Reordering a simple java object into a 3 levels objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following example object that contains objects, and i want to reorder it:

```
var thisarray = {
    0 : { topic: "devices/one/humid/value", message: "1"},
    1 : { topic: "devices/one/humid/unit", message: "%"},
    2 : { topic: "devices/one/temp/value", message: "2"},
    3 : { topic: "devices/one/temp/unit", message: "c"},
    4 : { topic: "devices/two/humid/value", message: "1"},
    5 : { topic: "devices/two/humid/unit", message: "%"},
    6 : { topic: "devices/two/temp/value", message: "2"},
    7 : { topic: "devices/two/temp/unit", message: "c"},
};
var arr = { };

for (var key in thisarray) {
    // skip loop if the property is from prototype
    if (!thisarray.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

    var obj = thisarray[key];
    var devicename = "";
    var variablename = "";
    var variableprop = "";

    for (var prop in obj) {
        // skip loop if the property is from prototype
        if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;

        if(prop=="topic") {
            var localstrings = obj[prop].split("/");
            devicename = localstrings[1];
            variablename = localstrings[2];
            variableprop = localstrings[3];
        } else if(prop=="message") {
            //this line throws an error
            arr[devicename][variablename][variableprop]=obj[prop];
        }
    }  
}
console.log(arr);
```

This throws an error

> `TypeError: Cannot read property 'humid' of undefined`

What i need as a result:

```
arr = {
    one : {
        humid : { value: 1 , unit : '%'},
        temp  : { value: 2 , unit : 'c'}
    },
    two : {
        humid : { value: 1 , unit : '%'},
        temp  : { value: 2 , unit : 'c'}
    }
}
```

I've been trying a lot of methods, and I've been looking on google but can't solve this, any guidance will be welcome

EDIT: thanks everyone, Tai Le's solution works perfectly, also thanks to Marcelo Origoni for pointing out my mistake too, i'm learning a lot here, thanks!

Comment: Mind you, those are not arrays, those are object that look like an array (though missing a `length` property). Why not use real arrays?

Comment: i want to use them on a template, so it becomes easier to use there, so i can display status per device, and every status with its value and unit, ie: device one - Temp 2 c, humid 1 %. This for several devices. If i put them on an array, i'll have numbered index instead of names, unless i'm doing it wrong, which is very possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't init value for nest property. This code may not exactly what you expect but point out what is your problem

```js
   var thisarray = {
    0 : { topic: "devices/one/humid/value", message: "1"},
    1 : { topic: "devices/one/humid/unit", message: "%"},
    2 : { topic: "devices/one/temp/value", message: "2"},
    3 : { topic: "devices/one/temp/unit", message: "c"},
    4 : { topic: "devices/two/humid/value", message: "1"},
    5 : { topic: "devices/two/humid/unit", message: "%"},
    6 : { topic: "devices/two/temp/value", message: "2"},
    7 : { topic: "devices/two/temp/unit", message: "c"},
   };
  var arr = { };

  for (var key in thisarray) {
     // skip loop if the property is from prototype
    if (!thisarray.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

  var obj = thisarray[key];

  var devicename = "";
  var variablename = "";
  var variableprop = "";

  for (var prop in obj) {
      // skip loop if the property is from prototype
      if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;


      if(prop=="topic") {
                var localstrings = obj[prop].split("/");
                devicename = localstrings[1];
                variablename = localstrings[2];
                variableprop = localstrings[3];
      } else if(prop=="message") {
          // Init value as empty object if it is undefined
          arr[devicename] = arr[devicename] || {};
          arr[devicename][variablename] = arr[devicename][variablename] || {};
          arr[devicename][variablename][variableprop]=obj[prop];
      }
  }  
}
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is clear, `arr[devicename]` is not defined, you should do it like this:

```
arr[devicename] = {};
arr[devicename][variablename]  = {};
arr[devicename][variablename][variableprop]=obj[prop];
```

that one, you define both `devicename` and `variablename` as empty objects, and you can create and modify it's attributes

Comment: how can i prevent it creating arr[devicename][variablename] again? else it will overwrite anything stored before that, is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: @user7360710 You could check if it is defined first. Simple way: `arr[devicename][variablename]  = arr[devicename][variablename] || {};` (which means if it's defined use it, if not then create a new object and use it from now on)

Comment: You are right, I forgot to check if the object already existed.